# Does a generic list initialized with another list copy values or the references?

Tags: c#, list

If I have a `List<T> Foo` and I initialize another `List<T> Bar` by passing `Foo` to the constructor for `Bar`, does `Bar` have access to the original objects in `Foo`?  Or are the objects in `Bar` separate copies?

Here's a silly example:

```
class Car
{
    public string Make   { get; private set; }
    public string Model  { get; private set; }
    public string Year   { get; private set; }

    public int FuelLevel { get; private set; } = 0;
    public int OilLevel  { get; private set; } = 0;

    public Car(string make, string model, string year)
    {
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
        Year = year;
    }

    public void Refuel()
    {
        FuelLevel = 100;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Car> CarsThatJoeOwns = new List<Car> { new Car("Ford", "Explorer", "2005"),
                                                    new Car("Hyundai", "Elantra", "2011") };

        // For some reason, Paul owns the exact same types of cars that Joe owns...
        List<Car> CarsThatPaulOwns = new List<Car> (CarsThatJoeOwns);

        foreach (Car car in CarsThatPaulOwns)
        {
            car.Refuel(); // <---- does this affect the cars that Joe owns too?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Car` is a reference type, because of that, the following will happen:

```
var car = new Car("Ford", "Explorer", "2005");
var carReference = car;
carReference.Refuel();

//Will have the value of 100, even if no method was called in the car
//object, but because it is a reference type, calling Refuel method
//on carReference will also affect to the variable referenced by
//carReference (car)
var fuelLevel = car.FuelLevel
```

In your code sample, you have this specific section:

```
List<Car> CarsThatJoeOwns = new List<Car>
{
    new Car("Ford", "Explorer", "2005"),
    new Car("Hyundai", "Elantra", "2011")
};

// For some reason, Paul owns the exact same types of cars that Joe owns...
List<Car> CarsThatPaulOwns = new List<Car> (CarsThatJoeOwns);
```

The `List<T>` constructor called when assigning `CarsThatPaulOwns` takes as parameter the already existing list `CarsThatJoeOwns`, which implements the interface `ICollection<T>`, so `CarsThatJoeOwns` can be casted to `ICollection<T>`.

Also, take a look at the source code for the constructor of the generic [**List**](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) class:

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
    if (collection==null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>;
    if( c != null) {
        int count = c.Count;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            _items = _emptyArray;
        }
        else {
            _items = new T[count];
            c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
            _size = count;
        }
    }    
    else {                
        _size = 0;
        _items = _emptyArray;
        // This enumerable could be empty.  Let Add allocate a new array, if needed.
        // Note it will also go to _defaultCapacity first, not 1, then 2, etc.

        using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
            while(en.MoveNext()) {
                Add(en.Current);                                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because `CarsThatJoeOwns` can be casted to an `ICollection<T>`, the line `c.CopyTo(_items, 0);` will be executed, and it does the following (as seen in the Microsoft Reference Source):

```
public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) {
    // Delegate rest of error checking to Array.Copy.
    Array.Copy(_items, 0, array, arrayIndex, _size);
}
```

And, as stated in the MSDN documentation, [**Array.Copy**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx) will do the following:

> ...**Remarks**...If sourceArray and destinationArray are both
>   reference-type arrays or are both arrays of type Object, a shallow
>   copy is performed. A shallow copy of an Array is a new Array
>   containing references to the same elements as the original Array. The
>   elements themselves or anything referenced by the elements are not
>   copied. In contrast, a deep copy of an Array copies the elements and
>   everything directly or indirectly referenced by the elements.

Please note the *"A shallow copy of an Array is a new Array containing references to the same elements as the original Array"* part. Simply put, the new list `CarsThatPaulOwns` will hold references to the already-existent objects in `CarsThatJoeOwns` list, and the `foreach` loop defined by:

```
foreach (Car car in CarsThatPaulOwns)
{
    car.Refuel();
}
```

will also affect the values in the `CarsThatJoeOwns` list. The vice-versa case will also be true (calling Refuel method on the `CarsThatJoeOwns` list will also affect the `CarsThatPaulOwns` list).

Comment: Why the downvote? Please add a comment to fix the answer properly (:

Answer (score 1):

This is the constructor of `List<T>`

```
    public List(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
        if (collection==null)
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>;
        if( c != null) {
            int count = c.Count;
            if (count == 0)
            {
                _items = _emptyArray;
            }
            else {
                _items = new T[count];
                c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
                _size = count;
            }
        }    
        else {                
            _size = 0;
            _items = _emptyArray;
            // This enumerable could be empty.  Let Add allocate a new array, if needed.
            // Note it will also go to _defaultCapacity first, not 1, then 2, etc.

            using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
                while(en.MoveNext()) {
                    Add(en.Current);                                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

if the collection can be an `ICollection<T>` then it will be copied to a new array.

If not it performs an `Add`:

```
    public void Add(T item) {
        if (_size == _items.Length) EnsureCapacity(_size + 1);
        _items[_size++] = item;
        _version++;
    }
```

Both instances looks like it is copying the reference of the items. However, the the array (a.k.a Foo) that is passed to the constructor has lost its reference. So that means, any updates to the first list won't updated the passed in list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your case, new list will be initialized with reference to existing Car objects. So calling `Refuel` function will result in both Paul an Joe cars being modified (since they are the same object).

Comment: I did indeed test this piece of code I have in the example above and you are correct that updating one list affects the others.  I'm not sure why someone gave you a -1.

Comment: Here you have a fiddle so that others will be able to verify: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m6GIWU  :)